# Compiling SVN from source on Ubuntu 8.04 / SSL

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I'm having problems compiling SVN 1.6.3 from source on our Ubuntu 8.04 development server.

I downloaded the 1.6.3 source files and dependencies and ran ./configure.  About 2 minutes into the process, it complains about:

```
configure: error: We require OpenSSL; try --with-openssl
```

So I try running ./configure --with-openssl, but then it complains that --with-openssl is not a recognized option.

I Googled the problem and found someone suggesting to do ./configure --without-ssl.  I tried that and it still complains about requiring OpenSSL.

The INSTALL file says that OpenSSL is optional, so I don't know what gives.  http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/INSTALL.  We don't need OpenSSL... we are using SVN via the svn://, not https://.

Any suggestions?

FYI:  I do not have root privileges on this server.  I'm "just" a developer.  The server admin says he'll run make install, but I have to do all of the prior steps.

Thanks!

Comment: What does ./configure --help say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boohbah@pwn2:~/subversion-1.6.3$ grep ssl configure
with_ssl
--with-ssl              This option does NOT affect the Subversion build
# Check whether --with-ssl was given.
if test "${with_ssl+set}" = set; then
withval=$with_ssl;
```

Try --with-ssl

Comment: Thanks!  I don't get the SSL complaint anymore.  Now it's complaining about RSA_new, but I'll open a new question for that if I can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem over the weekend. At the moment I am stuck with the Berkeley DB problem however installing the openssl-dev packages fixed the problem with SVN not compiling.